# Mysql IN clause only retrieving 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

Edit:
Thank you Baylor Rae and JvBerg - Your answers/comments helped solve the problem.
I had to remove the quotes - Which I didn't realise.
Thank you all for your assistance.

---

I'm trying to select all data from the 'alerts' table `where ownerid='$friend_ids'` using the `IN` clause.
The problem I'm having (despite numerous googling and code changing) is it's only retrieving one row.

```
$fid=$ClassUsers->Friendids($user_id);
echo $fid;
```

Which returns (as expected) 1,2,3.

However when trying:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE ownerid IN('$fid')";
echo mysql_num_rows($db->query($sql));
```

Returns "1" row only.

My alerts table:

[image: Alerts table]

Does anyone know why? Or how to resolve this?
I've literally spent all night yesterday, the day before and a few hours today googling and trying different ways to query this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `$fid`

Comment: And what is the value of `$fid`? What does your final query look like?

Comment: What @BaylorRae' said - echo out your SQL, and run it in the database - it'll tell you exactly what the error is.

Comment: You had better make sure `$fid` isn't coming from the user or an untrusted class!

Comment: @BaylorRae' - I cannot believe it. That was the problem. How I never thought of this I don't know...Thank you.
Deceze - `$fid=$ClassUsers->FriendIds($user_id);` as above. `$fid` then returns whats in the `userfriends` table. In this case, it returns `1,2,3`.
Andrewsi-Tried it and had the same problem, until I removed the `'`.
user113215 - It's not and it's sanitized in the class anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$fid` is an array, you will need to do something like

```
$fid_sql = implode(','. $fid);
$sql="SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE ownerid IN( $fid_sql )";
```

Note you shouldn't need single-quotes around each value here if they are integer fields in the DB.

If `$fid` is a string = "1, 2, 3", then all you need to do is get rid of the single-quotes around `$fid` in your query.

Comment: I did implode the array, and as you said, I turned it into a string - What I didn't know was to remove the quotes which was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value of $fid:

```
$fid = '1, 2, 3';
$sql="SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE ownerid IN( $fid )";
echo mysql_num_rows($db->query($sql));
```

Will return all 3 rows.

Comment: Nope. It'll only returns rows whose `ownerid` is literally "1, 2, 3".

Comment: No, `IN ('$fid')` will only return rows `WHERE ownerid = "1, 2, 3"`. The values must be quoted individually -- example: `WHERE ownerid IN ('1', '2', '3')` -- or may not be quoted at all if they are numeric -- example: `WHERE ownerid IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Look how I wrote IN ( $fid )! Tutorial here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Next time I provide a SQLFiddle as proof ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting your values

```
IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Otherwise it looks for the value that is literally '1, 2, 3' not '1' or '2' or '3'.